# Rails 4 SQL query rails way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

i have this query, which I want to se in rails way. Could please anyone help me here?

```
select * from users
  ,buyer_events
  ,supplier_events
where (users.id = buyer_events.buyer_id
      or users.id = supplier_events.supplier_id)
      and supplier_events.event_id = 11
      and buyer_events.event_id = 11;
```

PostgreSQL

If more information is needed just write in comments :)

Comment: do you have to select all users which match the where cond?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ He is selecting all columns from table users, not all users.

Comment: have you the two separate tables: buyer_events, and supplier_events?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it should be something like this:

```
class User
  has_many :supplier_events
  has_many :buyer_events

  scope :with_event, ->(event_id) {
    joins(:supplier_events, :buyer_events).merge(supplier_events.for_event(event_id)).merge(buyer_events.for_event(event_id))
  }
end

class SupplierEvent
   belongs_to :supplier, class_name: :User
   belongs_to :event, class_name: :Event

   scope :for_event, ->(event_id) { where(event_id: event_id) }
end

class BuyerEvent
   belongs_to :buyer, class_name: :User
   belongs_to :event, class_name: :Event

   scope :for_event, ->(event_id) { where(event_id: event_id) }
end
```

Then issue:

```
User.with_event(11)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def self.buyers_and_suppliers user_id
    joins(:buyer_events, :supplier_events).where(users: {id: user_id}, supplier_events: {event_id: 11}, buyer_events: {event_id: 11})
  end
  ...
end
```